# Rewriting query to use analytic functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with client's id, creation_datetime, company and a binary (0 or 1) column checked. I wrote a very slow query

```
    select a.id
          ,a.creation_datetime
          ,a.company
          ,count(*) as num_all -- number of all rows
          ,count(distinct b.id) as num_cl -- number of distinct clients
          ,count(case when b.checked = 1 then 1 end) as checked_all -- number of rows checked
          ,count(distinct case when b.checked = 1 then b.id end) as checked_cl -- number of clients checked
    from table a
    join table b on a.company = b.company
                 and b.creation_datetime < a.creation_datetime 
    where add_months(a.creation_datetime, -12) <= b.creation_datetime 
    group by a.id, a.creation_datetime, a.company;
```

I would like to use analytic functions as they are usually faster than self join on a table (I would like to avoid cartesian product on a large table). My ideas are

```
    count(*) over (partition by company order by creation_datetime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_all

    count(case when checked = 1 then 1 end) over (partition by company order by creation_datetime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as checked_all
```

I've two issues here.

1. count(distinct) doesn't work with order by clause.
2. I don't know how to impose condition add_months(a.creation_datetime, -12) <= b.creation_datetime. Is it even possible while using analytic functions?

**Edit**
id is not unique. Pairs (id, creation_datetime) are unique. The meaning of (id, creation_datetime) is that client with id applied on creation_datetime. Each application is checked or not. One client can apply many times with many different companies. The goals:

i) for each (id, creation_datetime, company) count the number of applictions (pairs (id, creation_datetime)) having the same company within 12 months,

ii) for each (id, creation_datetime, company) count the number of distinct clients id having the same company within 12 months,

iii) as i) but only checked applications,

iv) as ii) but only checked applications.

**Edit 2**
Sample data and results
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7156/2
Notice that some rows don't satisfy join conditions and they are excluded from the results. That's fine, I can add rows with zeros later or use left join when the query becomes more efficient.

**Edit 3**
The rows that do not appear in the results should have zeros. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7156/23

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  Isn't the `id` column unique?

Comment: Please provide sample data in convenient format as follows: https://gist.github.com/xtender/3a06d70808a966ad620874fabc567ec6

Comment: oracle version?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov: 19c

Comment: @stolikp _"Notice that some rows don't satisfy join conditions and they are excluded from the results. That's fine, I can add rows with zeros later..."_ - if you remove `where num_all>0` in my answer - you will get all rows.

Comment: _"Notice that some rows don't satisfy join conditions and they are excluded from the results. That's fine, I can add rows with zeros later..."_ Could you just show what do you exactly need, not you get? Because looks like it would be easier to make what you need, than rewrite this self-join with strange limitations.

Comment: @stolikp please look at previous question

Comment: @Sayan Malakshinov See edit 3.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect a column named `id` to be unique, so `count(distinct)` is not necessary:

```
select a.*, count(*) over (partition by company) as num_all,
       sum(checked) as num_checked_all,
       row_number() over (partition by company order by creation_date) as running_count,
       sum(checked) over (partition by company order by creation_date) as running_checked
from a
```

Comment: I have edited my question. id is not unique. I should have used different name for it.

Comment: @stolikp . . . Provide sample data and desired results.  A db/sql fiddle is also helpful.

Comment: I have edited my question. The data and results are given.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7156/7

**Update**: modified as per test data from sqlfiddle.

```
with pre_range as (
   select
      c.*
     ,to_number(to_char(creation_datetime,'yyyy.mmddhh24miss')) dtnum
   from test_tab c
)
,add_new_clients as (
   select
      p.*
     ,decode(
         count(*)over(partition by company,id order by dtnum range between 1 preceding and 0.00001 preceding)
        ,1,1 -- case when 1 then 1
        ,0,1 -- case when 0 then 1
        ,0   -- else 0
      )  as new_client
   from pre_range p
)
select *
from(
    select a.id,dtnum
           ,a.creation_datetime
           ,a.company
           ,count(*)
              over(partition by company order by dtnum range between 1 preceding and 0.00001 preceding)
            as num_all -- number of all rows
           ,sum(new_client) 
              over(partition by company order by dtnum range between 1 preceding and 0.00001 preceding)
            as num_cl -- number of distinct clients
           ,count(case when checked = 1 then 1 end) 
              over(partition by company order by dtnum range between 1 preceding and 0.00001 preceding) as checked_all -- number of rows checked
           ,sum(case when checked = 1 then new_client else 0 end) 
              over(partition by company order by dtnum range between 1 preceding and 0.00001 preceding) as checked_cl-- number of clients checked
    from add_new_clients a
    )
where num_all>0
order by id,creation_datetime;
```

Full test case with sample data:

```
with test_tab(id, creation_datetime, company, checked) as (
select 1, to_date('2019-05-13 13:27:28', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'company_a', 0 from dual union all
select 2, to_date('2019-05-12 13:27:28', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'company_a', 0 from dual union all
select 3, to_date('2018-05-12 13:26:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'company_a', 0 from dual union all
select 2, to_date('2019-05-11 13:27:28', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'company_a', 1 from dual union all

select 4, to_date('2019-05-13 13:27:28', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'company_b', 1 from dual union all
select 1, to_date('2019-05-12 13:27:28', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'company_b', 1 from dual union all
select 1, to_date('2018-05-12 13:26:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'company_b', 0 from dual union all
select 2, to_date('2019-05-11 13:27:28', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'company_b', 1 from dual 
)
,pre_range as (
   select
      c.*
     ,to_number(to_char(creation_datetime,'yyyy.mmddhh24miss')) dtnum
   from test_tab c
)
,add_new_clients as (
   select
      p.*
     ,decode(
         count(*)over(partition by company,id order by dtnum range between 1 preceding and 0.00001 preceding)
        ,1,1 -- case when 1 then 1
        ,0,1 -- case when 0 then 1
        ,0   -- else 0
      )  as new_client
   from pre_range p
)
select *
from(
    select a.id,dtnum
           ,a.creation_datetime
           ,a.company
           ,count(*)
              over(partition by company order by dtnum range between 1 preceding and 0.00001 preceding)
            as num_all -- number of all rows
           ,sum(new_client) 
              over(partition by company order by dtnum range between 1 preceding and 0.00001 preceding)
            as num_cl -- number of distinct clients
           ,count(case when checked = 1 then 1 end) 
              over(partition by company order by dtnum range between 1 preceding and 0.00001 preceding) as checked_all -- number of rows checked
           ,sum(case when checked = 1 then new_client else 0 end) 
              over(partition by company order by dtnum range between 1 preceding and 0.00001 preceding) as checked_cl-- number of clients checked
    from add_new_clients a
    )
where num_all>0
order by id,creation_datetime;
```

Comment: There is a problem with num_cl  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db565/3

Comment: @stolikp ah, yes, I forgot to replace "current row" in add_new_client with "0.00001 preceding". I have fixed the answer, please check it again

Comment: @stolikp to be honest, I think your variant with self-join returns all values less than it should: you join 2 different rows with different clients, but num_cl shows 1.

Comment: There would be a similar problem for checked_cl for a right data set. The way you mark new_client is independent of other clients sharing the same company. By the way, thanks for a nice idea with changing dates to numbers.

Comment: @stolikp you can remove "company" from "partition by". But I did the same as in your variant, as you put "company" into "group by"

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db565/3 For id = 2, you get num_all = 1 and num_cl = 0, so you get one application (row), but no distinct clients. The distinct client is in that 1 row. My results with self join: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db565/5

Comment: Why you didn't take nor my previous sqlfiddle  nor updated answer? As I said you need to replace "current row" with "0.00001 preceding"

Comment: Now it doesn't work with the first example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7156/8
Look at (1, to_date('2019-05-13 13:27:28', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'company_a', 0).
You get num_cl = 2, whereas you should get num_cl = 1.

Comment: @stolikp Comparing my http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7156/16 and yours http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7156/13 I wonder why do you ignore clients which are different in "A" and "B" when counting distinct clients? Ie `count(distinct b.id)` do not count different a.id. Look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89a9b/1 You are joining last row of A (id=2) with 2 rows from `b` (both of them id=1), but still get the same num_cl as in previous row where id=1.

Comment: num_cl is the number of distinct clients with the same company and earlier creation_datetime (at most year behind the current row). I do not count in the current row.  So the join is on company and there are conditions on creation_datetime. Then, I count the distinct clients.

Comment: @stolikp that's a bit strange since you count current row in num_all, but not in num_cl... any way try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7156/18

Comment: I do not count the current row for num_all, notice the join condition: b.creation_datetime < a.creation_datetime  - the row is not matched with itself. As for sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7156/18, now the 3 row example is not working - compare  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db565/13 with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db565/14

Comment: I mean different thing: compare the same ID set in different order: (1,1,2) and (1,2,1) - in your algorithm first one will give you num_cl (1,1), but second (1,2), and it gives you that finally you have 1 unique client for the first order and 2 unique clients with second one. Though you have the same clients.

Comment: About your previous comment "As for sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7156/18, now the 3 row example is not working - compare sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db565/13 with sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db565/14" - you testing wrong sql, you missed NVL()

Comment: you can tune my query as per your needs - it's pretty easy, I'm too tired to analyze your requirements